# Read Excel Macros Programmatically in PHP or JS

Tags: excel, parsing, vba

How to extract macros in Excel file in PHP or JS?

I found https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/ but there is nothing about macros.

Comment: Have you had any luck solving your problem? Did the answers you got help you? Please provide a follow-up to your question.

Comment: No. I was trying to extract a ransomware macro from an Excel file, but it was an 2003 Excel format and it is really an binary file format than other Excel format which in fact an zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You asked a similar question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1188859/read-excel-macros-programmaticly-in-php-or-js-or-another-language).

The easiest way with PHP is to make a system call to a python [script](https://github.com/unixfreak0037/officeparser):

```
shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/usr/bin/python officeparser.py macro.xlsm --extract-macros"));
```

and then check the created files. The directory can be set with the `-o` parameter.

If you want a PHP-only solution, I couldn't find any and you would need to bake your own. PHPExcel can help getting the VBAProject.bin binary data as `private $macrosCode`. You could then try to decode the VBAProject.bin binary data either by looking at what [other tools](https://www.decalage.info/vba_tools) do or by understanding its [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313094.aspx).